# Disabling autoescape using symfony and form_widget()

Tags: php, symfony

Using Symfony 2, I'm trying to print out a label by using

```
form_widget(form.client)
```

The label I'm trying to print is containing actual HTML markup:

```
$builder->add('client', 'text', array('label' => '<a href="#">Client</a>'));
```

But Symfony autoescapes the label and prints it out as text and not as HTML. So I've tried to use both

```
form_widget(form.client) | raw
```

and

```
{% autoescape false %} form_widget(form.client) {% endautoescape %}
```

but none of those two methods helped me, the output is still regarded as text and not HTML. 
Am I missing some setting or am I using it wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put HTML into your classes! Use [Custom Form rendering](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) to customize how your labels are rendered.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the tip. I didn't know about Customer Form Rendering

Answer (score 0):

I think Twig filters should be inside the parenthesis and not outside - have you tried like this :

```
form_widget(form.client | raw)
```

Also, I would recommend adding the  tag not in the class but directly in the template :

```
<a href="{{ your.variable }}"> {{ form_label(form.client) }} </a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but including the filter within the parenthesis didn't work. I'm starting to think that there is an escape function somewhere that I'm missing...